# Perl script giving un predictable results

Tags: perl

I am very new to Perl. I wrote a script to display user name from **Linux** passwd file. 
It displays list of user name but then it also display user ids (which I am not trying to display at the moment) and at the end it displays "List of users ids and names:" which it should display before displaying list of names.
Any idea why it is behaving like this?

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 @names=system("cat /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d :");
 @ids=system("cat /etc/passwd | cut -f 3 -d :");
 $length=@ids;
 $i=0;
 print "List of users ids and names:\n";
 while ($i < $length) {
    print $names[$i];
    $i +=1;
 }
```

Comment: You use the length of @ids for traversing through @names? This seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: it works fine because they're both of length 1 ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: `system` doesn't return output from a command; it returns the exit value. As the output of the `cut` isn't redirected, it prints to the current STDOUT (e.g. your terminal). Use `open` or `qx//` quotes (aka backticks) to capture output:

```
@names = `cat /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d :`;
```

---

As you are still learning Perl, here is a write-up detailing how I'd solve that problem:

First, always `use strict; use warnings;` at the beginning of your script. This helps preventing and detecting many problems, which makes it an invaluable help.

Next, starting a shell when everything could be done inside Perl is inefficient (your solution starts six unneccessary processes (two sets of `sh`, `cat`, `cut`)). In fact, `cat` is useless even in the shell version; just use shell redirection operators: `cut ... </etc/passwd`.

To open a file in Perl, we'll do

```
use autodie; # automatic error handling
open my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd";
```

The `"<"` is the mode (here: reading). The `$passwd` variable now holds a *file handle* from which we can read lines like `<$passwd>`. The lines still contain a newline, so we'll `chomp` the variable (remove the line ending):

```
while (<$passwd>) {  # <> operator reads into $_ by default
  chomp; # defaults to $_
  ...
}
```

The `split` builtin takes a regex that matches separators, a string (defaults to `$_` variable), and a optional limit. It returns a list of fields. To split a string with `:` seperator, we'll do

```
my @fields = split /:/;
```

The left hand side doesn't have to be an array, we can also supply a list of variables. This matches the list on the right, and assigns one element to each variable. If we want to skip a field, we name it `undef`:

```
my ($user, undef, $id) = split /:/;
```

Now we just want to print the user. We can use the `print` command for that:

```
print "$user\n";
```

From perl5 v10 on, we can use the `say` feature. This behaves exactly like print, but auto-appends a newline to the output:

```
say $user;
```

And voilà, we have our final script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; use autodie; use feature 'say';

open my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd";

while (<$passwd>) {
  chomp;
  my ($user, undef, $id) = split /:/;
  say $user;
}
```

#### Edit for antique perls

The `autodie` module was forst distributed as a core module with v10.1. Also, the `feature 'say'` isn't available before v10.

Therefore, we must use `print` instead of `say` and do manual error handling:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

open my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd" or die "Can't open /etc/passwd: $!";

while (<$passwd>) {
  chomp;
  my ($user, undef, $id) = split /:/;
  print "$user\n";
}
```

The `open` returns a false value when it fails. In that case, the `$!` variable will hold the reason for the error.

Comment: I originally did as you mentioned @names = `cat /etc/passwd | cut -f 1 -d :`; but when I displayed $name[$i] it displayed the exact command. If you could modify and run the script at your end, you will understand me better. Thanks

Comment: @user2026794 I tried it with backticks, and it worked fine. Are you sure you didn't use ordinary quotes?

Comment: You are right, I did user single quotes.  Thank you so much for detailed explanation, it will help so many people in future. When I run your script it gives me "Permission denied" error. I guess password file should have more liberal permissions?

Comment: @user2026794 I tested the script on my system, where it ran fine (of course, `/etc/passwd` has `rw-r--r--` as permissions; owner is root). What OS and what perl (first line of `perl -v` output) are you using?

Comment: Perl version: v5.8.8. I have Oracle Linux i.e. cat /proc/sys/kernel/{ostype,osrelease,version}
Linux
2.6.32-300.10.1.el5uek    Also the permission of my file is ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2394 Mar 11 21:26 /etc/passwd I am using root account

Comment: @user2026794 **Never use root, especially when copy&pasting code from the internet**. Also, my condolences for having to use that OS. I added an update that targets older perls (pre-v10). Does that work?

Comment: Still same problem: # ./a.pl
-bash: ./a.pl: Permission denied
[root@db1 perl]# cat a.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

open my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd" or die "Can't open /etc/passwd: $!";

while (<$passwd>) {
  chomp;
  my ($user, undef, $id) = split /:/;
  print "$user\n";
}

Comment: @user2026794 It seems like your problem could be fixed with `chmod +x a.pl` (making the script executable). You can also invoke Perl scripts like `perl a.pl`, which doesn't require the script to be executable, as it is fed directly to the perl interpreter.

Comment: You are right. It fixed the issue. I thought root account should be able to access/execute all files. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

For reading of system databases you should use proper system functions:

```
use feature qw(say);

while (
    my ($name,    $passwd, $uid, $gid,   $quota,
        $comment, $gcos,   $dir, $shell, $expire
    )
    = getpwent
    )
{
    say "$uid $name";
}
```

Comment: Get permission error. ./b.pl
-bash: ./b.pl: Permission denied

Comment: @user2026794 How you invoke your script? `perl b.pl` should work or insert `#!/usr/bin/perl` but don't forget `chmod +x b.pl` first.

Comment: Ok. You are right. say didn't work so I had to convert to print. I guess perl version issue. Thanks for the code.

Comment: say has been around for a while, but you might need "use feature 'say';" at the head of your file to switch it on. It's just print with an implicit newline, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're scanning the entire password file, you can use `getpwent()`:

```
while( my @pw = getpwent() ){
  print "@pw\n";
}
```

See `perldoc -f getpwent`.